# ffmpeg mingw compilation 8192 char limits

Tags: ffmpeg, mingw-w64, msys

I´m trying to compile ffmpeg shared with mingw64 on Windows 10.
Here is the configure command:

```
./configure --arch=x86_64 --enable-shared --disable-static --prefix=/e/Downloads/ffmpeg-dyn/
```

Everything looks ok.
Then I make:

```
mingw32-make.exe -j16
```

But I encounter this error:

```
LD      libswresample/swresample-3.dll
LD      libswscale/swscale-5.dll
dlltool -m i386:x86-64 -d libswresample/swresample-3.def -l libswresample/swresample.lib -D swresample-3.dll
dlltool -m i386:x86-64 -d libswscale/swscale-5.def -l libswscale/swscale.lib -D swscale-5.dll
STRIP   libavcodec/x86/vp9itxfm.o
GEN     libavcodec/libavcodec.ver
EXTERN_PREFIX="" AR="ar" NM="nm -g" ./compat/windows/makedef libavcodec/libavcodec.ver libavcodec/012v.o libavcodec/4xm.o libavcodec/8bps.o libavcodec/8svx.o libavcodec/a64multienc.o 
... // SKIP all .o files for stackoverflow
libavcodec/y41pdec.o libavcodec/y41penc.o libavcodec/ylc.o libavcodec/yop.o libavcodec/yuv4dec.o libavcodec/yuv4enc.o libavcodec/zerocodec.o libavcodec/zmbv.o libavcodec/zmbvenc.o > libavcodec/avcodec-58.def
Object does not exist: lib
mingw32-make: *** [ffbuild/library.mak:102: libavcodec/avcodec-58.dll] Error 1
```

As you can see Object does not exist: lib does not mean anything. After some investigations it looks like this is due to cmd.exe 8129 character limitation for parameters. I tried to set a different ComSpec value, without success. I also tried to do some changes in library.mak Using a file containing *.o files but I encounter many errors.

It looks like this is a known issue but nothing I tried works : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6620

Any tips to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Carl Eugen from ffmpeg-user mailing list.

I changed ffbuild/library.mak line 67-70

```bash
$(SUBDIR)$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR): $(OBJS) $(SHLIBOBJS) $(SLIBOBJS) $$(SLIBOBJS) $(SUBDIR)lib$(NAME).ver
    EXTERN_PREFIX="$(EXTERN_PREFIX)" AR="$(AR_CMD)" NM="$(NM_CMD)" $(SRC_PATH)/compat/windows/makedef $(SUBDIR)lib$(NAME).ver $(SUBDIR)*.o > $$(@:$(SLIBSUF)=.def)
    $$(LD) $(SHFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDSOFLAGS) $$(LD_O) $$(filter %.o,$$^) $(FFEXTRALIBS)
    $(SLIB_EXTRA_CMD)
```

And for each dll problems, use this :

```
$ mingw32-make.exe V=1 libavcodec/avcodec-58.dll
```

description: mingw32-make.exe V=1 subdirlib/libname.dll

Complete discussion with Carl Eugen available here : https://www.mail-archive.com/ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org/msg19801.html

EDIT (23/06/2022) : adaption of the answer to the [20b0d24](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/20b0d24c2f7ae86cebeb17399a2fea3a7e3d0f69#diff-3ab7710430be418ed02677056298485cafde1aa3aaf78baf57b2362d248b9387) commit

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU make instead of mingw32-make. This works for me at least.
Install GNU make using 'pacman -S make' if you were using msys2.