# ffmpeg mingw compilation 8192 char limits - revisited

Tags: ffmpeg, mingw, msys2

When I change line 51 of library.mak as in [ffmpeg mingw compilation 8192 char limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852242/ffmpeg-mingw-compilation-8192-char-limits/61148838#61148838) I get an error:

ffbuild/library.mak:107: *** target pattern contains no '%'. Stop.

Help pls

Comment: Please provide the failing code. Otherwise, we can only guess the code from the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

So the ./configure creates custom build macros in a file - config.mak
The solution in [ffmpeg mingw compilation 8192 char limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852242/ffmpeg-mingw-compilation-8192-char-limits/61148838#61148838) is for that specific configuration.

The fix is actually replacing $(OBJS) in the SLIB_EXTRA_CMD macro with $(SUBDIR)*.o

Best done in the configure script